# How can I fix my code to make it function?

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP (and in programming altogether). I have watched a video explaining the basics, so I decided to play around with PHP by myself; I wrote this code:

```
 <?php 

 $people = [
    array("John", "smart"),
    array("Mike", "dumb"),
    array("Jose", "smart"),
    array("Emmanuel", "dumb")
 ];

 foreach ($people as $name => $intelligence) {

 };

 echo $name [0][0]." "."is ". $intelligence[0][1];

 ?>
```

I'm trying to output:

> John is smart

However, it outputs:

> is m

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please clarify: do you actually mean to output just one line, just for the first pair, or are you trying to output one line per pair?

Comment: Just the first pair. I'm trying to output "John is smart".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<?php 

 $people = [
    array("John", "smart"),
    array("Mike", "dumb"),
    array("Jose", "smart"),
    array("Emmanuel", "dumb")
 ];

 foreach ($people as $name => $intelligence) {

 };

 echo $name [0][0]." "."is ". $intelligence[0][1];

 ?>
```

to this

```
$people = [
"John" => "smart",
"Mike" => "dumb",
"Jose" => "smart",
];

    foreach ($people as $name => $intelligence) {

      echo $name." is ". $intelligence;

     };
```

Comment: although this would work - OP may want to keep array format. Also, it would be better to use arrays using name and intelligence as keys

Answer (score 2):

Your array data (per item) looks like this:

```
[
    'john',
    'smart'
]
```

There is no key association to these values. So in your output example, what you actually need to do is:

```
foreach ($people as $el)
{
    echo $el[0]. ' is ' .$el[1];
}
```

Your data is a numerically indexed array, starting at 0. So 0 = john and 1 = smart.

It would be better to structure your array like this:

```
$people = [
    0 => [
        'name' => 'john',
        'intelligence' => 'smart'
    ], # etc.
];

foreach ($people as $el)
{
    echo $el['name']. ' is ' .$el['intelligence'];
}
```

here we're using named keys that make sense.

In your code example you do this:

```
foreach ($people as $name => $intelligence)
```

but `$name` in your loop is actually the item key.. so 0, 1 etc. and intelligence is the array. Not the name and intelligence as you think.

However, if you're literally just trying to echo out the first element, just do:

```
echo $people[0][0]. ' is ' .$people[0][1];
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. But why did you write " 0=>"? I took that off the code, and the output is still the same.

Comment: @overfl0w That's just adding numeric keys - it does do this be default, I just prefer to see it there for my slow eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you meant:

```
<?php

$people = [
array("John", "smart"),
array("Mike", "dumb"),
array("Jose", "smart"),
array("Emmanuel", "dumb")
];

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo $person[0] ." is ". $person[1]."<br/>";
}
```

Your `people` array is fine if that's really the way you want to write it.
You could instead declare it like the following. As another exercise, why don't you declaring the array like this and they modify the rest of the code so it prints what you want.

```
$people = [
"John" => "smart",
"Mike" => "dumb",
"Jose" => "smart",
"Emmanuel" => "dumb"
];
```

Your `echo` statement was outside of the for loop. I moved it inside.

The way you were reading your `people` array didn't seem quite right, so I've changed it to:

- `$person[0]` - Get the zeroth element in the inner array, the name
- `$person[1]` - Get the first element in the array, the intelligence

Comment: No, they want to print just for the first array, not them all.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca really? I read the example as just how they want to echo the output .. I'll comment for clarification

Comment: @treyBake they finally answered. They want the first pair only.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca my whole array explanation .. for nothing?! ahhhh haha xD le sigh

Comment: @treyBake I actually upvoted your answer because it was the most complete one and included the intended case :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca <3 well at least it wasn't for nothing fully then :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function passing it params eg. Name to find and array of people.

```
<?php 

 $people = [
    ["John", "smart"],
    ["Mike", "dumb"],
    ["Jose", "smart"],
    ["Emmanuel", "dumb"]
 ];


 function return_Sentence( $name , $array ){
    foreach ($array as $details) {
           if($name == $details[0]){
                return $details[0] . ' is ' . $details[1];
           }
    }
  return 'Not Found';
 }

 echo return_Sentence( "John" , $people );

 ?>
```

Comment: Think op meant `function` as in make it work, not make it into a function.

Comment: Yeah it was just his expected output that threw me, only had 1 name

Comment: Agreed, the question is really confusing, and apparently OP is in no hurry to clear it up.

Comment: Apologies, Jon is right. I meant "function" as in to make it work.

Comment: All goods, either way can still be used if looking to print 1 name.